# WooCommerce - Dash in product title breaks loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm running this query:

```
// find books that have this author
$author_name = get_the_title();                     

// args
$booksby_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
     'tax_query'     => array(
         array( 
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_author-woo',
          'terms'    => $author_name, 
          'field'    => 'name'
         ), 
      ), 
);

// The Query
$thebooks_query = new WP_Query( $booksby_args );

// The Loop
if ( $thebooks_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<h3>Books by '.$author_name.'</h3>';
  echo '<ul class="author-entry__book-list">';
  while ( $thebooks_query->have_posts() ) {
    $thebooks_query->the_post();

    $productObj       = get_page_by_title( get_the_title(), OBJECT, 'product' );
    $productId        = $productObj->ID;        
    $wc_product       = wc_get_product( $productId );                       

    echo '<li class="clearfix">'; 
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $productId ).'">';
    echo the_post_thumbnail('shop_thumbnail');
    echo '<div class="author-entry__book-info">';
    echo '<p class="title">'.get_the_title().'</p>';                          
    echo '<p class="price">'.$wc_product->get_price_html().'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

But whenever the title of a product contains a '-', the output just seems to fail after it's echo'ed the title. There's not even an empty `<p class="price">` tag. Other elements lower down my template don't get outputted either.

Also, if I try define define a variable for the price, e.g. `$wc_price = $wc_product->get_price_html()` before all the echo statements, none of the echos render at all!

If I comment out the price echo or if the product title doesn't contain a dash, It all works just fine.

This is a snippet of what it outputs when it fails:

```
<div class="author-entry__book-info">
<p class="title">Rogue &#8211; The Inside Story Of SARS&#8217;s Elite Crime-busting Unit</p>
</div>
```

Help me understand please!

Comment: Why do you do this: `$productObj       = get_page_by_title( get_the_title(), OBJECT, 'product' );` - It seems you want to get the post object of your product, but you have it already.

Comment: Because I'm no Wordpress pro and wasn't sure how else to get the product ID ;")

Comment: Okay umm, I'm not sure why, but fixing that issue you brought up @AndyTschiersch sorted it all out :)


Just getting the product ID as simply as this now: `$productId = get_the_ID();`